# Перевод textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Можно ли реализовать перевод (на английский,польский,русский и немецкий) содержимого textarea (вводит посетитель) на другой язык внутри самого textarea?Например, при клике на кнопку

Comment: теоритически да. нужно бесплатно зарегистрироваться на сервисе перевода (будет выдан ключ). далее по клику на кнопке посылать текст на сервис, получать ответ и обновлять текст в текстбоксе.

Comment: можно подробнее.я не очень в этом разбираюсь

Comment: @Garmi Подробнее уже готовый код получится, но попробую уточнить первый комментарий.. Ищете API сервис перевода, получаете ключ, подключаетесь, отправляете туда свое содержимое textarea, сервис этот текст переводит и возвращает вам, а вы с ним делаете уже что хотите, можно создать рядом textarea и поместить перевод туда

Comment: а как именно отправлять?

Comment: вот какой-то туториал. https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/